# How can I prevent a custom excel hyperlink from triggering with either dragging the fill handle--I only want it to respond with a click

Tags: excel, vba, function, hyperlink

Ok so I have a hyperlink function in a spread sheet cell of the form:

```
=HYPERLINK(JJmp(I1030), I1030)
```

With the function JJmp():

```
Function JJmp(x) As String  

dim iint as variant
iint = x

If IsNull(iint) Then GoTo out:
If Left(iint, 1) <> "_" Then GoTo out:

pat1 = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"""

'pat1 = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe""" (this is the default, and I don't want to change the reg).

pat3 = "D:\__Numerical_Files_by_Page\" & iint & ".pdf"

pat3 = """" & pat3 & """"

Shell pat1 & " " & pat3, vbNormalFocus

JJmp = x

out:
End Function
```

For whatever reason the hyperlink based on this function has some very odd behavior.  As stated in the title dragging the fill handle doesn't just fill the cells but also opens adobe for each one.  Secondly, the hyperlink is super sensitive, I don't have to even click on it--just hovering over it will trigger acrobat 10 to open.

In essence its a very unstable hyperlink in that it is nearly self triggering.  If I use the function directly I get an entry that requires some return key gymnastics to open acrobat.

I would just like this to respond like a normal hyperlink.  TIA

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is because everytime you hover over the link or you drag it to a new field, excel tries to resolve the link before you click it meaning it executes your function. How else would it be possible for excel to keep your link up to date and provide it before you click it?
-> Your Function is not executed at the time to click at it as excel thinks, your function returns a link, which it then can follow.

You could try something like this:
[herber hype2macro](http://www.herber.de/xlfaq/workshop/hype2macro/hype2macro.html).

Comment: Slai and Julian thanks for the quick feedback, must study your approaches in more depth.  Julian's explanation is interesting.  I guess more generally such things present dilemma's to excel architects which probably first is realized by many such as myself in terms of things like "well if I could just do this it would work, but probably not because that would cause an infinite loop..."  If all else fails there is at least an opportunity for an increase in understanding...

Answer (score 1):

then don't use `Shell` in your UDF. What you want is more like this

```
Function JJmp(x) As String
    If Not IsNull(x) And x Like "_*" Then _
        JJmp = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"" " & _
               """D:\__Numerical_Files_by_Page\" & x & ".pdf"""
End Function
```